# How to Restrict NSLog in Distribution and Release Mode -iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to Enable the `NSLog` only in Debug Mode. I need to restrict `NSLog` in Distribution and Release mode.

I am using the code below,

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#   define NSLog(...) NSLog(__VA_ARGS__);
#else 
#   define NSLog(...)
#endif
```

But it's not working. anyone please explain me as brief as possible. Where should i use the code in every `NSLog` statement or Every class or only in .PCH class..

Thanks for your consideration and Effort

Comment: If i want to anything in Build settings please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Write this to your .pch file

```
#ifndef DLog
#ifdef DEBUG
#define DLog(_format_, ...) NSLog(_format_, ## __VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define DLog(_format_, ...)
#endif
#endif
```

After this use DLog instead of NSLog to meet with your goal

Comment: i put the same code u given in .Pch and am using DLog instead of NSLog. DLog is coming in console when am running in device.

Answer (score 1):

Put this into your `.pch` file

```
#ifndef DEBUG
#undef NSLog
#define NSLog(args, ...)
#endif
```